# Hiding sections of text for certain users

Tags: users

In my drupal site on certain pages I want to hide certain links or bits of text in the body field for particular roles..
I might want to do something like

either

```
hide this text for custom_role_1 but show it for all other users
```

or something like

```
switch
 case role = anon, then print this text
 case role = custom_role_1, then print this text
 case role = custom_role_2, then print this text
```

now I know I could achieve this using field_permissions and just create a field for each role type - but that feels like overkill... as it's only a few times I'll be needing this..
what I'm thinking is, is there a bit of php someone could show me that I could just stick in there instead? I could switch from editing those pages from using the wysiwyg to the php-input edit mode???

Answer (score 2):

Aside from field permissions, you could make sure that the information you want to hide is separated from the rest of the content in its own block and restrict the ability to view it to certain roles, which is essentially what it appears you want to do, only not in php.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but no not quite, I need just the odd sentence or link to change within in the the body text of a page depending on the role of the user who is viewing. Using blocks would be rather cumbersome for that... I'm looking for a php snippet really..

Comment: So you want to run all of the content through a filter before being displayed, and hide parts depending on the role of the user? You realise, you won't be able to cache pages doing that, and aside from the resource drain on filtering all of the content on every load, without caching it will slow it down that much more.

Comment: you could look at code filter (https://drupal.org/project/codefilter) for some of the logic and code for filtering the text - you will need to come up with a set of standards to define areas that get filtered, and what they are filtered by.

Comment: I was hoping it'd be easier than that.. I'll have to talk to a proper coder... I thought there'd be something simpler... maybe i'll have to do it with blocks after all. I didn't think what I was asking would be difficult.